# Is the maximum possible charge on an object asymmetrical with regard to polarity?

Tags: charge

I am not a physicist so I am not sure how to check my intuition. Hence my question here.

Suppose I wish to charge a sphere to the maximum extent.

Intuitively I imagine the following:

1. I can give the sphere an indefinite amount of negative charge by continuing to add electrons indefinitely.
2. On the other hand I can remove only a finite number of electrons from the sphere and so there is a hard limit on the positive charge that I can generate. (That limit is reached  when no electrons remain)

Now I can understand that there may be **some** limit to the number of electrons that can be added but it is not obvious to me that is has any connection to the number that can be removed.

**Question**

Is the maximum charge, that a given object can sustain, different according to whether it is a positive or negative charge?

Comment: a macroscopic piece of metal has on the order of $10^{23}$ atoms and the same number of free electrons representing a charge of of $10^4C$, that is an incredible amount of charge. A $1mF$ capacitor biased at $1kV$, if there is creature like that, has only $1C$ charge, so there is a limit before the *free-electron free* metal explodes in space....

Answer (score 0):

The number of electrons that can be removed or added is negligible when compared with the total number of electrons in the material. The asymmetry you imagine does not exist.